# Cannot share PowerAutomate Flows with out the creators credentials

Tags: power-automate

I would like to share a Flow made through PowerAutomate with many co-workers, but I am having issues with the connector references. This flow triggers using the Office 365 connector for Outlook. I need to share this flow with 50+ people, have the Flow use the end users credentials, and be able to send updates.

There seems to be three ways to share flows:

1. **Send a copy**, under the flow. This will share a template of the flow of which the user can create a local copy of my flow. It correctly uses the individuals credentials for users. The problem is if I need to update the flow, everyone will have to recreate it, and i will have to reshare it.
2. **Share**, under the flow. This adds users as *owners* who can edit and modify my flow, but it uses my credentials. The flow needs to use the individuals credentials to trigger on receiving an O365 email.
3. **Solutions**. There is an option to create a *Solution* which a flow can be part of. These can be managed and have versions. The problem here is similar to method 2, where it seems to still use my personal credentials.

What is the best method to share a flow with the following criteria:

- Use the end users credentials for connectors, not the Flow creators
- Share/Distribute with 50+ users
- Update the flow for all users

Answer (score 0):

If the trigger is the only point it matters to be unique, ie your not trying to send emails as part of the flow (unless you give send on behalf of access for all users to the adminuser account running the flow?) or if you do and you don't care if it comes from a different account.

Then split it into 2 Flows, you can create a shared outbox folder in a sharepoint document library etc, their flow triggers on email and puts .eml in the outbox, updates sharing rights so only relevant can see/access, adds the user to a person column etc.

Your flow triggers off a new file being created in that library and uses dynamic content of the person column to join up the email to the identity in O365 and go about doing whatever your Flow needed to do with that email?